Use IntegerChoices instead of Model for rest framework
I have field like this,
models.py
from django.db import models as m

class Faculty(m.IntegerChoices):
    Arts = 1, 'Arts',
    Scienece = 2, 'Sceience'
    Other = 3 ,'Other'

and it is used as reference in other models.
Howeber, now I want to get the list by API rest framework.
For example if it is not IntegerChoices but Model
I can use the rest framework with view and serializer
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = sm.Faculty.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.FormSelectorSerializer

class MyModleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    detail = serializers.JSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = sm.MyModel
        fields = ('id')

I can use the rest framework like this ,
However for IntegerChoices, How can I do the equivalent to this thing?
Or is it possible?

Does this answer your question? Django Rest Framework with ChoiceField
